# Basic Objective-C for Java Developer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The syntax of ObjC for iPhone looks way too confusing. I'm sure this post will help and save not only my time, but also those who start working with ObjC.

1. How do I create and call a function inside a class?
2. How do I pass arguments when calling a function, both primitive and objects?
3. How do I create a global variable (primitive and object) that I can access all over the class? (I tried declaring an array in .h class, set the values in ViewDidLoad method and access it from other method, and it DIDN'T work!).

Comment: All these questions are already answered on SO. Please look around and post a more focused question if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer with examples.

Q: How do I create and call a function inside a class?

A: Pretty much the same as in Java. Just a bit of different syntax. Example

```
//Java:
private string exampleMethod {
  return "it is an example";
}
//somewhere in the code:
System.out.println("example output: " + exampleMethod);

//Objective-C :
-(NSString)exampleMethod {
  return @"it is an example";
}
//somewhere in the code:
NSLog(@"example output: %@", [self exampleMethod]);
```

Q: How do I pass arguments when calling a function, both primitive and objects?

A:

```
//Java:
private int calculateSum(int i1, int i2) {
  return i1 + i2;
}
//somewhere in the code:
int someInt = calculateSum(8, 23);

//Objective-C :
-(int)calculateSumOf:(int)i1 and:(int)i2 {
  return i1+i2;
}
//somewhere in the code:
int someInt = [self calculateSumOf:8 and:23];
```

Passing on objects is exactly the same as primitives:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:23];
[self someMethodThatNeedsAnInt:8 andSomeRandomObject:myNumber];
```

Q: How do I create a global variable (primitive and object) that I can access all over the class? (I tried declaring an array in .h class, set the values in ViewDidLoad method and access it from other method, and it DIDN'T work!).

A: If you only need to access it IN your class then do something like that in your `.h`(header) file:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject {
  int itIsAnExampleOfIntVariable;
  YourOtherClass *itIsAnExampleOfObjectVariable;
}
```

and don't forget to include `#import "YourOtherClass.h` if you are using it. After that you can just use these variables in your class.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I really, *really* suggest reading a big book on Objective-C, but I'll give you a cheat sheet in the mean time:

Create a function:

```
@interface ClassName

- (void) methodName;
```

Call the function from the class implementation:

```
[self methodName];
```

Call the function from a different class:

```
ClassName* class = [[ClassName alloc] init];
[class methodName];
```

Function with arguments:

```
- (void) methodName:(NSString*)aStringArgument;
```

Calling function with argument:

```
[self methodName:@"theArgumentStringBeingPassed"];
```

Declare class variable:

```
@interface ClassName
{
    NSString* aStringVariable;
}
```

Access it from the class implementation:

```
@implementation ClassName

- (id) init
{
    aStringVariable = @"aString";
}
```

Synthesize getter and setter for the variable:

```
@interface ClassName
{
    NSString* aStringVariable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* aStringVariable;
```

The implementation:

```
@implementation ClassName

@synthesize aStringVariable;
```

Get it:

```
self.aStringVariable
```

Set it:

```
self.aStringVariable = @"newString";

//OR

[self setAStringVariable:@"newString"];
```

Again, you'll definitely want to dive deep into the language to really feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

[cocoa dev cenral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/) website covers the basic. There are lots of ios blogs available over the net. Try googling a specfic topic, I am sure you will get lots of tutorial or samples.